# PayPal Sandbox approval URL stuck in infinite loop

Tags: paypal, sandbox

I've got a strange issue with PayPal's Sandbox / API V2.

After creating an order with the `AUTHORIZE` intent (pre-auth). I'm taking the user to the APPROVE URL, and after selecting the payment method PayPal *says* that it's redirecting me back to my redirect_url, but instead it just reloads the payment selection screen.

I don't know what's wrong....  This is what I'm passing directly to the API:

```
curl -v -X POST https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer <my-access-token>" \
-d '{
   "intent":"AUTHORIZE",
   "description":"Description goes here",
   "soft_descriptor":"Descriptor",
   "purchase_units":[
      {
         "amount":{
            "currency_code":"CAD",
            "value":"351.75"
         }
      }
   ],
   "order_application_context":{
      "return_url":"redacted_for_privacy",
      "cancel_url":"redacted_for_privacy"
   }
}
```

That call is obviously working as PayPal is returning the `CREATED` response.  I have looped through the returned HATEOAS links and redirected the user to the approve URL ... Then the problem starts...

API response is:

```
{
  "id": "8KF74291SN313461D",
  "intent": "AUTHORIZE",
  "status": "CREATED",
  "purchase_units": [
    {
      "reference_id": "default",
      "amount": {
        "currency_code": "CAD",
        "value": "351.75"
      },
      "payee": {
        "email_address": "sb-iuaiy3198427@business.example.com",
        "merchant_id": "DXYXG2JAU3SQQ"
      }
    }
  ],
  "create_time": "2020-09-15T05:13:59Z",
  "links": [
    {
      "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/8KF74291SN313461D",
      "rel": "self",
      "method": "GET"
    },
    {
      "href": "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/checkoutnow?token=8KF74291SN313461D",
      "rel": "approve",
      "method": "GET"
    },
    {
      "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/8KF74291SN313461D",
      "rel": "update",
      "method": "PATCH"
    },
    {
      "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/8KF74291SN313461D/authorize",
      "rel": "authorize",
      "method": "POST"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Hard to say anything about what's going on without details about your testing attempts like the API response body with an order ID, or debug ID header.  So, try testing with a new Business and new Personal account created at https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Faccounts%2F -- create the necessary Rest App for that new Business account.

Comment: @PrestonPHX Thanks Preston. I just tried with a new Business+Personal account, and it still loops. I'll wait to hear back from PayPal support. I've updated the question to include the body response (it's successful, so I think the issue is on PayPal's side).

Answer (score 2):

Issue was their confusing API documentation.

`order_application_context` **should be changed to:** `application_context` in the API Call

Comment: Thank you, it works after I've changed order_application_context to application_contex